# bottomNavigationBar is showing labels when showSelectedLabels and showUnselectedLabels is set to false (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

Was messing around with the `bottomNavigationBarTheme` and noticed that the label was showing on the selected item even though `showSelectedLabels` was set to `false`. Is this a bug or am I missing something?
This behavior only holds true as long as the property is declared in the `ThemeData` when moved to the `bottomNavigationBar` it behaves as expected.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'app',
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
        canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(52, 58, 70, 1),
        bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
          selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
           color: Color.fromRGBO(113, 124, 152, 1),
           size: 28,
          ),
          unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(196, 201, 212, 1),
            size: 28,
          ),
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
        ),
        cardColor: Color.fromRGBO(52, 58, 70, 1)
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('appbar'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Text here'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
            title: Text('a'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.view_day),
            title: Text('a'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.equalizer),
            title: Text('a'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
            title: Text('a'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            title: Text('a'),
          ),

        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of app]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That has to do with the `BottomNavigationBarType`.
if you are using more than 3 Items in `BottonNavigationBar`, you have to set the `type` to `BottomNavigationBarType.fixed`

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
```

this has been already discussed on the Flutter github issue page:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13642#issuecomment-353945439

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way and worked for me and that too with type `BottomNavigationBarType.shifting`

```
showUnselectedLabels: true, unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by multiple way

1. use Text("");
2. remove title

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using title, instead of that you should use label without Text() as shown below:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
            label:'a',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.view_day),
            label: 'a',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.equalizer),
            label: 'a',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
            label: 'a',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            label: 'a',
          ),

        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

U should use this code :

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
   //use both properties
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
  //-----------
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.icon1),
        label:'item 1',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.icon2),
        label: 'item 2',
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

when you new the BottomNavigationBarItem, add the "tooltip:''"

Comment: Can you show an example code of what you trying to show and if it helps the question or not?